# Finding alpha in pmf $P(X=i) = \frac{\alpha}{2^i}$

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, random-variable, density-function

I have to solve the following problem: 
Let X be distributed over N (natural numbers) with probability mass function $P(X=i) = \frac{\alpha}{2^i}$ for some fixed alpha (which is an element of R, the real numbers). Find alpha.

I know that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P(x=i) = 1$. Therefore $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha}{2^i} =  \frac{\alpha}{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}2^i}= 1$ and $\alpha = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}2^i$. But this cannot be right as $\alpha$ would be infinite and we are looking for a fixed alpha.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha}{2^i} \neq  \frac{\alpha}{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}2^i}.
$$
Just as $1/2 + 1/3 \neq 1/5$. Also recall that $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a^i = (1-a)^{-1}$ as long as $|a| < 1$.

Comment: Thank's for the hint. But I don't succeed in rearranging my equation so that I can apply it. What would be $a$ and what $k$?

Comment: @motormiquel sorry I made a small typo. See the edit.

Answer (score 2):

Ok here is my try, please correct me if I'm wrong.

$s_n = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P(X=i) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha}{2^i} 
= \frac{\alpha}{2}+\frac{\alpha}{4}+\frac{\alpha}{8}+...+\frac{\alpha}{2^n}$

Then, $2s_n  = \frac{2\alpha}{2}+\frac{2\alpha}{4}+\frac{2\alpha}{8}+...+\frac{2\alpha}{2^n}$

$= \alpha+\frac{\alpha}{2}+\frac{\alpha}{4}+\frac{\alpha}{8}+...+\frac{\alpha}{2^{n-1}}$

$= \alpha + s_n -\frac{\alpha}{2^n}$

and $s_n = \alpha-\frac{\alpha}{2^n}$.

If now $n\rightarrow \infty, s_n \rightarrow \alpha$. And as $s_n$, the sum over all probabilities, must equal $1$, $\alpha = 1$.

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha}{2^i} 
= \frac{\alpha}{2}+\frac{\alpha}{4}+\frac{\alpha}{8}+...+\frac{\alpha}{2^n}$ you have an extra $\alpha$

Comment: Right, thank's. I've made the corrections above, please verify!

Comment: nice! Looks good 